# Not able to use a key from a merged dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got two dataframes that both have a date column and an emaX column, when I merge them I get the expected result of a single date column and two emaX columns. But when I try access the date key from the merged dataframe, it returns a KeyError: date.

This is the function that returns the emaX (I have two, but they're nearly identical):

```
def av_get_ema_20():
    ti = TechIndicators(key=TOKEN, output_format="pandas")
    emaData20, meta_ema = ti.get_ema(symbol=SYMBOL, interval=INTERVAL, time_period=20, series_type=EMA_TYPE)
    ema20renamed = pd.DataFrame(emaData20)
    ema20renamed.rename(columns={'EMA': 'ema20'}, inplace=True)
    return ema20renamed
```

Then I merge the two returned dataframes:

```
mergedDF = pd.merge(av_get_ema_10(), av_get_ema_20(), on=["date"], how="inner")
# TEST LINE
print(mergedDF)
```

The dataframe that is printed out appears as I expected it to be:

```
                         ema10      ema20
date                                     
2020-01-02 11:30:00  3226.5200        NaN
2020-01-02 12:30:00  3229.0927        NaN
2020-01-02 13:30:00  3232.0558        NaN
2020-01-02 14:30:00  3235.0839        NaN
2020-01-02 15:30:00  3239.1668        NaN
...                        ...        ...
2020-03-26 11:30:00  2524.9545  2473.8551
2020-03-26 12:30:00  2533.1755  2483.0279
2020-03-26 13:30:00  2541.2982  2492.0586
2020-03-26 14:30:00  2551.0458  2501.8540
2020-03-26 15:30:00  2565.2866  2513.9983
```

But then when I attempt to use the merged dataframe (for ex. interating through the dataframe), I get KeyError: date:

```
for index, row in mergedDF.iterrows():
   print(row["date"], row["ema10"], row["ema20"])
```

Am I misinterpreting the dataframe in some way or is there something else I am supposed to do prior to using the merged set (including the date)? I'm at a loss here.

Comment: `date` is your Index, which you unpack to `index` in your loop, so `print(index, row["ema10"], row["ema20"])`

Comment: @ALollz That was it, thank you!